# Number of non negative integral solutions involving exponents

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, combinations

I know if $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 \leq k$ then number of integral solution can be given by ${k + 4} \choose 4$ using [Stars and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) but I am unable to figure out no. of integral solutions of $x_1 + x_2^2 + x_3^3 + x_4^4 \leq k$. where $ 0\leq x_1, x_2 ,x_3, x_4 \leq 10^3 $ and $0 \leq k \leq 10^{18}$. Kindly help.

Comment: The number of nonnegative integer solutions of the inequality $x_1  + x_2  + x_3 + x_4 \leq k$ is the number of nonnegative integer solutions of the equation $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + s = k$, where $s = k - (x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4)$, so you should have obtained $\binom{k + 4}{4}$.

Comment: sorry. My Bad. Yes it should be ${k + 4} \choose {4} $. I have edited it